# Why is my "required" validator not replacing the standard breeze required validator with registerFactory?

Tags: entity, metadata, breeze, validation

Because Breeze Required validator is not working correctly, we want to replace it by our own implementation. For this, I have this TS code which gets called before I validate my property:

```
breeze.Validator.registerFactory(
(ctx?: breeze.ValidatorFunctionContext) =>
    new breeze.Validator(
        'required',
        (value: string, context: breeze.ValidatorFunctionContext) => {
            if (context.hasOwnProperty('allowEmptyStrings') && !context['allowEmptyStrings'] && typeof value === 'string') {
                return value != null && value.length > 0;
            }
            return value != null;
        },
        ctx),
'required');
```

When I trace the registerFactory method, I see the implementation of the required function changes in the indexable property.

```
__config.functionRegistry[fnName] = fn;
```

Now, when I run this code to validate my property:

```
this.isValid(this.entity.entityAspect.validateEntity());
```

And I trace the code right inside the validate method in breeze:

```
 function validate(aspect, validator, value, context) {
```

the required validator is the wrong one, its the breeze one, not mine?

What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the breeze docs [(see here)](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation) "registerFactory" is only necessary when you load previously exported data. It says:

> We think it's a good practice to register your custom validators although you don't have to unless you'll be getting metadata from a serialized source other than the server. Play it safe; register them.

*"... you don't have to unless you'll be getting metadata from a serialized source"* means the other way round: the factory registration is useless in all other places. If you look in the breeze code line 6922 ff., function addValidators(dataProperty): it does not check the function registry. Maybe someone of the breeze team can explain this more exactly.

Best way to do it: create your own validator then add it manually to your entity or property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you can see in my code above, we needed to replace the default required validator because it doesn't handle allowemptystring properly, there's a bug in breeze code. I'll offer our solution in an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Breeze source code (1.4.11) at line 2320 to say:

```
if (ctx && (ctx.allowEmptyStrings || ctx.property && ctx.property.allowEmptyStrings)) return true;
```

instead of:

```
if (ctx && ctx.allowEmptyStrings) return true;
```